# $B: \mathbb R\times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the function $B(a,b) = ab $. Which of the following is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

$B: \mathbb R\times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$   be the function   $B(a,b) = ab $. Which of the following is true?

1)  $B$ is a linear transformation

2) $B$ is a positive definite bi-linear form

3)$B$ is symmetric but not positive definite.

4) $B$ is neither linear nor bi-linear.

I can not understand how to proceed. This is certainly not linear. But how can I check whether it is bi-linear or not. Can anyone help me to understand what is the concept of bilinear and how to check whether it is bi-linear or not?

Comment: What is your definition of bilinear? There should be a list of properties to check.

Comment: I do not have any definition. I was given this problem to solve. I have knowledge about linear mapping. But I do not know anything about bilinear map.@Arthur

Answer (score 0):

1) $B$ is not linear because $B(\lambda a, \lambda b) = \lambda^2 ab \neq \lambda B(a,b)$ in general.

2) $B$ is bilinear : indeed, you can check that $a \mapsto B(a,b)$ (when $b$ is fixed), and $b \mapsto B(a,b)$ (when $a$ is fixed) are both linear. Moreover $B$ is positive definite because for all $a$, $B(a,a) = a^2 \geq 0$, and this vanishes only when $a=0$.

3) $B$ is symmetric because $B(a,b)=B(b,a)$.

Comment: Can you please tell me little more on bilinear map? How to check a function whether it is bilinear or not?  @TheSilverDoe

Comment: A bilinear map is a map that is linear with respect to its two variables. More precisely, $(x,y) \mapsto B(x,y)$ is bilinear if and only if $x \mapsto B(x,y)$ and $y \mapsto B(x,y)$ are both linear.

Comment: Honestly I can not accept your answer because no body upvotes ..I am really confused whether you are correct or wrong. But your answer seems to be correct..Anyway can you share any link where I can read more about this?@TheSilverDoe Mar

Comment: I think nobody upvotes because it is quite a tautological answer for anyone who knows what is a bilinear map... But of course my answer is correct ;) Here is all you need to know about bilinear maps : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map